# Can EFCodeFirst work with the existing aspnetdb.mdf?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity

As opposed to create the new one automatically, how to force the EFCodeFirst to use the existing aspnetdb.mdf in app_data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful:

[Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)

Comment: Thank for the link. I will upvote your answer later after passing the minimum reputation barrier.

Answer (score 1):

If your domain mappings are in direct correlation to the existing database then yes.

Comment: I have 2 classes `Student` and `Course`. Both are not related to asp.net roles and membership tables direclty. Is there a chance to make EFCodeFirst create `Student` and `Course` in `aspnetdb.mdf`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this url. I think the name speaks for itself :) http://nuget.org/List/Packages/EFCodeFirst.CreateTablesOnly